Average with dynamic range
I want to average the values of a row in the form of a 10-element interval and store the output in another array and finally display that array. In this way, the average is taken from the first house to the tenth house and it goes to the house. The first array. After the second cell to the eleventh cell, I take the average and the result goes to the second cell of the array and so on until the last cell of that row.
I wrote this formula and it works, so I wanted to see if anyone could write a simpler formula.
=transpose(mmult(index(1:1,sequence(((count(1:1)/10-1)*10+1),10)+mmult(sequence(((count(1:1)/10-1)*10+1),1,0,-9),sequence(1,10,1,0)))/10,sequence(10,1,1,0)))

I want the formula to be presented in an Excel cell only and receive the output as a line

=MAP(SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(1:1)-9),LAMBDA(s,AVERAGE(INDEX(1:1,,SEQUENCE(,10,s)))))


Or
=MAP(SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(1:1)-9),LAMBDA(s,SUM(INDEX(1:1,,SEQUENCE(,10,s)))/10))


Where MAP goes from cell 1 to the final used cell minus 9 from the row and uses that as the start value of a sequence of 10 to use inside INDEX. The average is returned for each.

If you don't have access to MAP() you could use
=TRANSPOSE(MMULT(INDEX(1:1,,SEQUENCE(,10)+SEQUENCE(COUNTA(1:1)-9,,0)),SEQUENCE(10)^0)/10)

